# OnAppear executed when it's not selected on the TabView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, tabs

I'm trying an authenticated flow in my app.

The app has a `LoginScreenView` that is going to appear first on the app.
When logging in, we go to a TabView consisting of two Views, `FirstView` and `SecondView`.
`SecondView` has a logout button, that returns the user to the login screen.
On the `FirstView` we have a network call that is being performed always `onAppear`.

When the user logs out, we are on the `SecondView`, on the second tab; however both `onAppear` and `onDisappear` functions of the `FirstView` are being executed, even though `FirstView` is not on display.

This provokes in our use case to trigger the network call in the `onAppear` method of `FirstView` that will fail because we are not authenticated.

Here is my code.

This is `LoginScreen`:

```
struct LoginScreenView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var authManager: AuthManager
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Login") {
            authManager.isLoggedIn = true
        }
    }
}
```

This is `FirstView`:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .tabItem {
            Label("Hello", systemImage: "globe")
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("First ✅")
            Task {
                try await loadSomeStuffFromNetwork()
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            print("First ❌")
        }
    }
}
```

This is `SecondView`:

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var authManager: AuthManager
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "flag.fill")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Goodbye, world!")
            Button("Logout") {
                authManager.isLoggedIn = false
            }
        }
        .tabItem {
            Label("Goodbye", systemImage: "flag")
        }
        .onAppear {
            print("Second ✅")
        }
        .onDisappear {
            print("Second ❌")
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the root view of the app:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var authManager = AuthManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Group {
                if isLoggedIn {
                    FirstView()
                    SecondView()
                } else {
                    LoginScreenView()
                }
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(authManager)
    }
}
```

It's using the `AuthManager` declared in here:

```
final class AuthManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = false
}
```

As you can see in the code, we are trying to change the displayed views depending on whether we are logged in or not, and we use an `if-else` for that.

Do you think this code is OK? Do you feel that this might be a bug on the Apple side? I feel like this should work out of the spot, but I don't know if I'm missing anything.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74079950/swiftui-onappear-called-when-tabview-is-released) from 2022, but it seems it never got resolved (apart from the workaround of adding a condition of being logged in to perform the network call).

Also, saw this [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64495887/7716213), where they propose to use a `@State` variable to make the view only perform one network call instead of everytime it appears (or SwiftUI decides it to appear).

Are we OK on this train of thought? Should we try to build our network call in some other way?

Comment: Don't use `@State` to track logged in status. Use an observable model object that you inject into the environment

Comment: Yeah, in our application we have it as an environment object. Let me update it to that.

Comment: I would add a `guard` to check if you are logged in to the network code.

Comment: That was one way to do it. However, we would need to add similar code in every view that is going to appear in the TabView, which would add too much code everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

TabView SwiftUI has a bug and it makes each tab render many times. To fix it you can use LazyView.

```
struct LazyView<Content: View>: View {
 let build: () -> Content
 init(_ build: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Content) {
    self.build = build
 }

 var body: Content {
    build()
 }
}
```

Use:

```
func tabViewRegion() -> some View {
    TabView(selection: $viewModel.tabViewCurrentIndex) {
        LazyView(YourView1())
            .tag(0)
        LazyView(YourView2())
            .tag(1)
    }
}
```

I hope Apple will fix it soon as soon.

Comment: It seems like a lightweight change, let me try this and see if it works as expected.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I'm afraid this doesn't work still, it still calls the onAppear method every now and then.

Comment: I personally think u just change the value of the variable binding to the tab view. View re-render.

Comment: We thought that should work too, but it seems the Views inside the TabView are still cached in some way, even if we remove the TabView from the hierarchy.